# Showing that the convolution of two Borel measures is a Borel measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convolution, borel-sets, borel-measures

A book I am reading (Mattila's *Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension*) defines the convolution of two Borel measures $\mu, \nu$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$ sort of implicitly as $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi(x)d(\mu\ast\nu)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi(x + y)d\mu(x)d\nu(y)$ for any continuous non-negative function $\varphi$ with a compact support, $\varphi\in C_0^+(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$. I know that this might be completely trivial question, but if that is the definition of the convolution between two Borel measures, how do we then show that $\mu\ast\nu$ is itself a measure (or a Borel measure)? Can we approximate the indicator function of any Borel set by a continuous non-negative function with a compact support? Or is there some good-to-know result which gives this immediately?

Comment: No, we can't approximate the indicator function of any Borel set by a continuous function with compact support. What we can do, is to approximate any bounded and closed set (i.e. compact in $\mathbb R^n$) by such functions (if $K$ is compact, consider $\phi_n(x) = \max\{0,1-n\cdot dist(x,K)\}$). Then, you can approximate any closed set by the ascending sequence of compact sets. It remains to notice that Borel $\sigma-$algebra is generated by closed sets.

Comment: @DominikKutek If I wanted to show that $\mu\ast\nu$ is a Borel measure by first showing that it satisfies the measure properties on all closed sets and I wanted to work with only a single sequence of functions, could the following work: Let $\{K_k\}$ be a sequence of compact sets approximating an arbitrary, but fixed, closed set $C$. For every $k$ take $\varphi_{i,k}$ to be a continuous function sequence (like you proposed) converging pointwise in the index $i$ to $\chi_{K_k}$. Can we now take our sequence to be $\psi_k(x) := \varphi_{k,k}(x), x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?